# Finding dynamic/shared and static system libraries using ruby rake

Tags: c++, ruby, rake, libraries

I'm trying to write a rake task that can perform a guided search on the user's system for specific system libraries.  The basic idea is simple enough (in semi-pseudo-code):

```
def find_lib names, paths
    foreach name, path do
        return { :name => name, :path => path } if File.exists? File.join(path, name)
    end

    return false
end

find_lib ['mylib1.2', 'mylib12'], ['/usr/lib', '/usr/local/lib']
```

My actual implementation is a little more elegant, but this shows the basic idea. However, I would like to make this OS agnostic, which throws a few big wrenches into the gears. Each operating system has potentially different prefixes and extensions for a library.  For instance, a shared library could be ".dll", ".so', or ".dylib" depending on the current system. So far, I've come up with a solution that involves building a map of prefixes/extensions based on the current operating system:

```
settings = {}
settings[:dylib_ext] = OS.windows? && ".dll"   ||
                       OS.mac?     && ".dylib" ||
                       ".so"
```

This works to some extent, although it only covers the dynamic library case, and also relies on an external gem "OS", which I was trying to avoid.

Does anyone know a better way of accomplishing such a task, or if it is a solved problem (via another gem perhaps)?  The main thing I'm concerned about is the map, which could get very cumbersome (not to mention that detecting the correct operating system is rather tedious at best, especially if you were to throw in cygwin or mingw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some thought, it seems that I have been too specific as to the user's current operating system, while what I really have wanted to determine has always been what functionality the user's system supports...  The approach that I ended up using was to determine a list of possible prefix/suffix combinations, and to check each of those.